Adding a css class to the gallery
I'm using WordPress 6.5 with the old editor, I'm trying to add a CSS class on the div gallery when it specified in the shortcode, the code doesn't work, can you help me ?
function custom_gallery_class($output, $attr) {
    if (isset($attr['class'])) {
        $output = str_replace('<div class="gallery', '<div class="gallery ' . esc_attr($attr['class']), $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter('post_gallery', 'custom_gallery_class', 10, 2);

Custom shortcode example :
[gallery size="medium" columns="2" link="file" class="custom-class" ids="46729,46728"]

Expected result :
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery custom-class galleryid-48105 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-medium">...</div>

Result :
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-48105 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-medium">...</div>


If you look at the gallery shortcode you will see that you are using the wrong filter. With post_gallery you can override the complete html of the shortcode. Your code performs a str_replace on an empty string, resulting in an empty return and subsequently the generation of the default gallery html.
Further on there is a filter called gallery_style which is meant to filter the gallery styles, but since the opening div is included you can also use to modify the classes.

Thank you very much for your answer, do you have an example ? I tried lots of basic thing but it doesn't work : function add_custom_gallery_class($gallery_style) {
if (isset($attr['class'])) {
return str_replace("class='gallery", "class='gallery custom-gallery-class", $gallery_style);
}
}
add_filter('gallery_style', 'add_custom_gallery_class');

The best thing to do is debugging by echoing intermediate results, for instance to check if the filter is called at all. Maybe your theme or some plugin is filtering as well, overruling your code.
